# Json how to display an information

Tags: php, json

How to display name ?

I tryiedthis but it does'nt work :  `$result_content_module->authors->name`

`var_dump($result_content_module->authors)` has the value of authors
also $result_content_module->title

```
{
 "title":   "Archive",
 "authors": [
  {
   "name": "MyName",
   "company":   "Company",
   "email": "emailopping.org",
   "website":   "website"
  }
 ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`authors` is an array within an object and its elements are again objects. Thereby, you would access the `name` attribute of the first author like so:

```
$jsonStr = '{
 "title":   "Archive",
 "authors": [
  {
   "name": "MyName",
   "company":   "Company",
   "email": "emailopping.org",
   "website":   "website"
  }
 ]
}';

$result_content_module = json_decode($jsonStr);
echo $result_content_module->authors[0]->name;
```

The snippet from above will print the following.

```
MyName
```

Live [Demo](https://3v4l.org/SamRR)

Beautify your JSON [here](https://jsonformatter.org/json-editor)

Comment: The '*Beautify your [...]*' is just noise. No need for it here.

Comment: If you confuse with long JSON, its give you idea about hierarchy. Its for future reference

Answer (score 1):

You have a mixture of [objects](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php) and [arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

Specifically, `authors` is an array so should be accessed using square bracket, rather than arrow, notation. In your example, the array has one entry so you want index 0.

Try:

```
var_dump($result_content_module->authors[0]->name);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your code snippet authors is an array of objects so you have to pass array index

```
$dt = '{
 "title":   "Archive",
 "authors": [
  {
   "name": "MyName",
   "company":   "Company",
   "email": "emailopping.org",
   "website":   "website"
  }
 ]
}';
$data = json_decode($dt);
echo $data->authors[0]->name;
```

Now if you have multi dimension array of authors then you have to use loop like following

```
    foreach($data->authors as $auth){
      echo $auth->name;
   }
```